# log file automatically created when open eclipse

Tags: eclipse

i am trying to open eclipse but it doesn't response .

it creates a log file automatically (`hs_err_pid#no.log`).

i tried to download another copy of eclipse but the same problem occur.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (signature.cpp:53), pid=3808, tid=1460
#  fatal error: expecting (
#
# JRE version:  (7.0_51-b13) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
```

Comment: When you redownloaded Eclipse, did you extract it to a completely new folder and run it from there or did you attempt to overwrite your old install?

Comment: Mention which OS are you using and which eclipse package you downloaded?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK It says Windows x86 in the dump text.

Comment: @supersam654 i extracted it to new folder and run it from there